# How to get Last day day and Today Data based on time limit

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have sample data here:

```
ID  Val            dt
1   Mohan   2017-10-13 13:02:49.493
2   Manasa  2017-10-12 20:02:49.493
3   maren   2017-10-13 18:02:49.493
```

When I run the statement today at 2 PM, it should give the result set of the last day 6 PM after Data, and today data up to this time and when I run the statement today at 7 PM, it should give today's data after 6 PM.

If I ran it at Today at 2 PM, the result will be like this

```
ID  Val            dt
1   Mohan   2017-10-13 13:02:49.493
2   Manasa  2017-10-12 20:02:49.493
```

If I ran at Today at 7 PM:

```
ID  Val            dt
3   maren   2017-10-13 18:02:49.493
```

Basic thing, if I ran before 6 PM it should give last day data before 6 PM and if i ran after 6 PM it should give today Data after 6 PM. I have tried with **DATE DIFF conditions** but am not able to justify the result - can any one please suggest?

Table Script

```
Declare @tab table 
(ID INT,Val Varchar(10),dt datetime)

Insert into @tab (ID,val,dt)
values (1,'Mohan','2017-10-13 13:02:49.493'),
(2,'Manasa','2017-10-12 20:02:49.493'),
(3,'maren','2017-10-13 18:02:49.493')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Now DATETIME, @FromDate DATETIME
SET @Now = GETDATE()
SET @FromDate = DATEADD( HOUR, 18, DATEADD( DAY, DATEDIFF( DAY, 0, @Now )
    - ( CASE WHEN DATEPART( HOUR, @Now ) < 18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ), 0 ))

SELECT @Now, @FromDate

SELECT *
FROM @tab
WHERE @FromDate < dt AND dt <= @Now
```

Result:

```
Now                     FromDate
----------------------- -----------------------
2017-10-13 19:36:40.963 2017-10-13 18:00:00.000

ID          Val        dt
----------- ---------- -----------------------
3           maren      2017-10-13 18:02:49.493
```

Explanation:

`@FromDate` is calculated as follows:

- `( CASE WHEN DATEPART( HOUR, @Now ) < 18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )` - if hour is less than 18 (6PM) then return 1
- `DATEADD( HOUR, 18, DATEADD( DAY, DATEDIFF( DAY, 0, @Now ) - ... , 0 ))` - return "6PM date", which is either yesterday or today depending on the result of the `CASE` expression above

Comment: can you implement this in given sample data...getting confused

Comment: @mohan111, can you provide create table scripts? You have enough reputation to know how to ask :)

Comment: Sure Alex i will modify the question

Comment: `@FromDate < DateValue` should be `@FromDate > DateValue`. If I were to run this after 6pm today it would return all 3 rows not just the row for maren, there is no closing bound for 6pm today

Comment: @NickFry-CSL - not sure what you mean, it works as expected. See updated answer with sample output

Comment: let me implement this one

Comment: @Alex - apologies, the dates and times changed from the original post so I had a mix in there; when I changed to those shown in the edited post it is working correctly

Comment: What I think I meant was that if there were dated values after the current time but before 6pm your solution would not pick them up, i.e. run at 2pm and a row dated at 4pm would not show. This assumes of course that entries can be future dated :)

Comment: @NickFry-CSL - I think OP wants data up-to now as opposed to up-to 6PM window. That's how I read it.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by creating two dates that simulate your day "window", i.e. 6pm yesterday and 6pm today, adjusting the concept of yesterday/today depending on whether the current time is before or after 6pm currently. You then simply select your data where `dt` is between those two dates (or use <= and > or whatever you need to include or exclude the relevant rows) e.g....

```
DECLARE @t table (ID int,Val varchar(30),dt datetime2(3))
INSERT @t(ID,Val,dt)
VALUES(1,'Mohan' ,'2017-10-13T19:02:49.493'),
      (2,'Manasa','2017-10-12T20:02:49.493'),
      (3,'maren' ,'2017-10-13T07:02:49.493');

DECLARE @now datetime2 = dateadd(HOUR,12,sysdatetime());

SELECT  *,
        @now,
        x.Today6pm,
        x.Yesterday6pm
FROM @t AS t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,'19000101',cast(@now AS date))-(CASE WHEN cast(@now AS time) < timefromparts(18,00,00,0,0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), CAST(timefromparts(18,00,00,0,0) AS DATETIME2(7))),
                    DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,'19000101',cast(@now AS date))+(CASE WHEN cast(@now AS time) > timefromparts(18,00,00,0,0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), CAST(timefromparts(18,00,00,0,0) AS DATETIME2(7))))) x(Yesterday6pm,Today6pm)
WHERE dt BETWEEN x.Yesterday6pm AND x.Today6pm
```

The `CROSS APPLY` here is to simplfy the code otherwise you could put those functions directly in the `WHERE` predicate.

the variable `@now` is simply used for testing to ensure the adjustment works rather than waiting until 6:01pm this evening. Obviously in your code just replace `@now` with `sysdatetime()`.

Note: if your dates are datetime then adding a date and time together "works" but it does not work for datetime2. The above approach will work for both datetime and datetime2 so is more resilient.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    ID  INT,
    Val VARCHAR(50)  ,        
    dt  DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO @T
VALUES
(1,   'Mohan  ', '2017-10-13 13:02:49.493'),
(2,   'Manasa ', '2017-10-12 20:02:49.493'),
(3,   'maren  ', '2017-10-13 18:02:49.493')

DECLARE @CURRENT datetime  = '13 oct 2017 18:00'
SELECT 
*
FROM @T
WHERE 
    (
        CAST(@CURRENT  as time) BETWEEN '00:00' AND '18:00' AND
        dt  BETWEEN  DATEADD(day,-1,DATEADD(hh,18,CAST(CAST(@CURRENT as date) as datetime))) AND DATEADD(hh,18,CAST(CAST(@CURRENT as date) as datetime))
    ) OR 
    (
        CAST(@CURRENT  as time) NOT BETWEEN '00:00' AND '18:00' AND
        dt >=DATEADD(hh,18,CAST(CAST(@CURRENT as date) as datetime))
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this script.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE 
( (CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) < '18:00') 
    AND dt < DATEADD(HOUR,18, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME) ) )
OR 
(( CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) >= '18:00' ) 
    AND dt >= DATEADD(HOUR,18, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME) ) )
```

Answer (score -3):

You could try this:

```
SELECT * FROM [yourTable] WHERE
(dt between CONCAT(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), ' ', '18:00:00.000') AND 
   CONCAT(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), ' ', '23:59:59.999')
   AND HOUR(GETDATE()) > 18)
OR
(dt between CONCAT(CAST(dt AS DATE) - INTERVAL 1 DAY, ' ', '18:00:00.000')
       AND GETDATE()
   AND HOUR(GETDATE()) < 18)
```

Comment: `DATE` and `NOW()` are not valid sql-server functions

Comment: Thought you were talking about mysql ;)